# How do I import from / install OpenZeppelin properly?

Tags: truffle, mist, openzeppelin, import

I'm a newb dev and want to play with smart contracts, and was trying to figure this out. Ive installed truffle and openzeppelin, everything seems to check out, but in Mist I still get an error when I try to import Math.sol saying it can't be found, what do I do?

Comment: Please provide code example of how you are trying to import `Math.sol`.

Comment: import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/math/Math.sol";

Comment: check the existent of the `openzeppelin-solidity` folder under node_modules to ensure that it was installed properly on your local machine

Answer (score 5):

Here are the full steps starting from a blank truffle project. You could replace `truffle init` with `truffle unbox <package>` if you want to start from a Truffle box.

1. Create a new directory
2. `truffle init`: initialize truffle in the directory
3. `truffle install zeppelin`: install open-zeppelin using [ETH Package Manager](https://www.ethpm.com/registry/packages/25)

A new folder will be created called `installed_contracts` which contains all the files.

You can import the `Math.sol` library by adding this line in your contract in the `contracts` folder:

```
import "installed_contracts/zeppelin/contracts/math/Math.sol";
```

Comment: Works, except you probably need to give a relative path, at least I had to, as in import "../installed_contracts/zeppelin/contracts/math/Math.sol";

Comment: Using the latest version of truffle with visual studio code, I did not need to specify a relative directory, but I am glad it worked one way or another.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the section about installing and using the libraries on the [official OpenZeppelin repo](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/README.md#installing-openzeppelin). There is a guide to correctly import and use libraries, such as Math.sol.

See below for an example:

```
import 'openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/ownership/Ownable.sol';

contract MyContract is Ownable {
  ...
}
```